# What is the SQL Query Syntax to write to a Date/Time Data Field in MS Access from LotusScript?

Tags: ms-access, lotus-notes, ms-access-2010, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a LotusScript (8.5.3) routine that writes Notes data from a view (8.5.3) to a Microsoft Access 2010 database using ODBC.  I'm using an SQL statement similar to the one below to write the data.  The problem I'm having is will the Syntax to get a Notes Date/Time value to an Access 2010 Date/Time value.

> strSQL=|INSERT INTO DATASHEET("DocumentNumber","RevisionNumber","RevisionDate") VALUES('| >+ docnum + |','| + docrevnum + |',{d'| + revdate.DateOnly + |'}|

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query >expression 'd '06/23/2010'}'

I'm sure my syntax is wrong, but I have tried multiple syntaxes that I have found referenced on the Web and none seem to work.

Can someone who really knows what the syntax should be and has code that is working,  please give me the correct Syntax.

UPDATE: I tried the following Syntax:

> strSQL=|INSERT INTO DATASHEET("DocumentNumber","RevisionNumber","RevisionDate") VALUES('| >+ docnum + |','| + docrevnum + |',#| + revdate.DateOnly + |#|

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in date in query expression '#'.

Thanks,

MJ

Comment: @HansUp I updated the original message with the results of your suggestion.  It at least knows it's a date.

Comment: It looks like LotusScript is using the pipe character (`|`) as its string delimiter, so I don't quite understand what the `>` is doing there. Also, you currently missing the closing `)`.

Comment: Another tip: When your date gets converted to a string make sure that it ends up as either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy/mm/dd`. If it winds up as `dd/mm/yyyy` you'll have problems. It's always best to explicitly specify the date format so you won't get messed up by machines with different regional settings. (BTW, `mm-dd-yyyy` and `yyyy-mm-dd` also work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HansUp's comment was the answer.  Below is what the Syntax ended up being:

The problem I had when I first ran it was that it came across a NULL date, so it didn't know how to process it.  So, I mad the following changes:

> If revdate.DateOnly="" then
>     rdate="01/01/1900"  'This is Access' equivalent to null date
>   else
>     rdate=revdate.DateOnly
>   end if
>
> strSQL=|INSERT INTO DATASHEET("DocumentNumber","RevisionNumber","RevisionDate") VALUES('| >+ docnum + |','| + rdate + |',#| + revdate.DateOnly + |#|

Thanks for the help.

MJ